# Scipy.optimize minimize 'inequality constraints incompatible'

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to minimize variance across a portfolio of 100 securities.

```
def portvol(w, x):
    return np.dot(w.T, np.dot(x, w))*252

covmat = annreturn.cov()
w0 = np.ones(len(covmat)) * (1 / len(covmat)) #equal weighting initially
bounds = ((0,1),) * len(covmat)
constraints =  {'fun': lambda i: np.sum(i)-1.0, 'type': 'eq'}
optweights = minimize(portvol, w0, args = (covmat), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bounds, constraints = 
      constraints)
```

annreturn.cov() is a 100x100 DataFrame.  The output is the same .01 even weightings I started with and this failure message:

```
message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
nfev: 102
 nit: 1
njev: 1
```

status: 4
 success: False

Answer (score 0):

This is how I calculated annualized returns...

```
annreturn = data.pct_change() #again, assuming percentage change 
annreturn = annreturn.iloc[1:]
annreturn = (annreturn+1)**252-1
```

If you don't notice anything off the bat, it's ok.  It took me 2 days to realize I didn't divide my PCT_CHANGE() result by 100.  Time well spent.  I was getting correlations to the powers of like 15+.  Here is what the last line should have looked like, and the minimize function from the original question works fine.

```
annreturn = (annreturn/100+1)**252-1
```

Sorry if anyone took time on this without the above piece!